# Pass python object as argument in pool.map(). Multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, object, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a function that takes an object and returns a pandas dataframe after doing some operations on the object's data members. This is a `commits` object from the `GitPython` library. I want to run this function in parallel using multiprocessing.
So I created pool object and used:

```
repo = Repo(path)
results = pool.map(func,list(repo.iter_commits('master')))
```

where `func` is:

```
def func(obj):
    return(pd.DataFrame({"date":[obj.commited_date],"author_name":[obj.author.name]}))
```

and the `obj_list` contains a list of commit objects created by using the GitPython library function `iter_commits()` like such:

```
obj_list = repo.iter_commits('master', max_count=10)
```

Doing this returns the following error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

This error doesn't show up when I pass a list of strings. It only gives this error when I pass a list of objects. 
How to fix this? And how to pass a list of objects to a function as argument to run it in parallel.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the `obj_list`?

Comment: what are the actual `obj`ects? are `name` and `filename` properties that might have some infinite recursion?

Comment: So I have only mentioned some dummy properties in the question. In reality I'm using the GitPython library to extract information about commits made to a local git repo. And the objects are all commit objects with properties like: commit.commited_date, commit.hexsha, commit.stats.files,commit.author.name etc.

Comment: @AndreasK. The `obj_list` is created using the `iter_commits` function of the GitPython library like such:
`obj_list = list(repo.iter_commits('master', max_count=10)`

Comment: Can you give a partial traceback of the exception? I realize that with a recursion error there are going to be lots and lots of lines, but if you could give the first few, and then a couple of the repeated lines it might narrow down what the issue is. I'd guess there's some problem pickling the commit objects, but I don't know the library and this seems like a strange error to be getting, so maybe it's something else.

Comment: @Blckknght 
  File "git.py", line 99, in <module>
    p.map(func, obj_list)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 266, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 424, in _handle_tasks
   put(task)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded